# Laravel 4 AJAX CSRF Token Mismatch (with _token)

Tags: laravel-4

I'm attempting to do a simple (soft) delete on my model from a customized implementation of the `frozennode/administrator` package. Whenever I hit my route via ajax, the application throws a `TokenMismatchException`.

I've tried with both `cookie` and `file` drivers set in the `session` config.

I have confirmed the `_token` is being submitted with the ajax request. Commenting the `csrf` filter out altogether allows me to successfully delete the record. I'm using the out-of-the-box `csrf` filter.

I'm also using the excellent [Sweet Alert](http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert) plugin, though that doesn't appear to be related.

**routes.php:**

```
//CSRF protection in forms
Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf'), function()
{

    //Delete Item
    Route::post('{model}/{id}/delete', array(
        'as' => 'admin_delete_item',
        'uses' => 'Frozennode\Administrator\AdminController@delete'
    ));

...
```

**Blade template:**

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete-item-button" data-token="{{ csrf_token()}} ">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    <span>
        &nbsp;Delete
    </span>
</a>
```

**Javascript:**

*Excuse my hellishness $.post is what's relevant.*

```
$('#delete-item-button').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var token = $(this).data('token');

swal({
    title: "Delete this record?",
    text: "There's no undo!",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
    closeOnConfirm: false
}, function () {
    $.post(
        window.location.pathname + "/delete",
        {"_token" : token},
        function(){
            swal({
                title: "Deleted!",
                text: "The record has been deleted.",
                type: "success"
            },
                function () {
                    window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'
                })},
        "json"
        );
    });
});
```

Any help or guidance would be **greatly** appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked in your browser debugger monitor what `token` is actually being set as when you click submit? Maybe its not correct?

Comment: The `_token` being passed in the XHR tab is the same as the `data-token` attribute. I'm not sure how to compare it against what it *should* be. Is there some way I can verify it is indeed passing the correct token?